# Автоматическое изменение DIV-а в зависимости от контента внутри него

Tags: html, css

Привет всем. Вот в чём вопрос. Есть у меня вот такой вот div
http://jsfiddle.net/Ploff_me/wB7Bj/embedded/result/
как мне сделать так, что б див с красным бордером не имел свободного места внутри? Что б его ширина вмешала ровно 3 внутренних дива и всё? Размеры и количество внутренних дивов будет меняться, фиксированный размер не подходит. Желательно всё это провернуть без js

коды:
http://jsfiddle.net/Ploff_me/wB7Bj/embedded/

```css
.main {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="block">uno</div>
    <div class="block">dos</div>
    <div class="block">tre</div>
    <div style="clear: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так http://jsfiddle.net/wB7Bj/2/.

```css
.main {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="block">uno</div>
    <div class="block">dos</div>
    <div class="block">tre</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>quattro
```

Comment: Увы, тоже не подходит. При сужении экрана и переносе элементов на другую строку не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен на счет кроссбраузерности, но вот такое решение работает.

```
.main{
border: 1px solid red;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: .main{
border: 1px solid red;
display: inline-block;
}

не подходит. Не работает, если элементы переносятся на другую строку.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f9vNx/

может так подойдет?
перенос работает при сужении окна браузера и при ручном переносе.